# Countifs in Sheets Returning Different Results in Different Cells Despite Locked Ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

time poster so here it goes...

I'm trying to count the number of employees whose average hours fall below their individual expectations and then sort those by a few different tag categories. For example I have this data:
[source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d4Dy.png)
you'll see their names (names blacked out but the data is there), individual expectations, role codes string, and a cell for their average hours which we'll be comparing to the expectation column to count.
So I have this countifs formula which appeared to work the other day:
[Formula and counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McI85.png)

that formula is:

```
=COUNTIFS(
'Weekly Team Stack - Billable'!$AH$5:$AH,"<"&'Weekly Team Stack - Billable'!$B$5:$B,
'Weekly Team Stack - Billable'!$D$5:$D,"*"&"#R&E"&"*",
'Weekly Team Stack - Billable'!$D$5:$D,"<>"&"*"&"#ARC"&"*",
'Weekly Team Stack - Billable'!$F$5:$F,"<>"&"PDX",
'Weekly Team Stack - Billable'!$F$5:$F,"<>"&"AP",
'Weekly Team Stack - Billable'!$C$5:$C,"Yes")
```

The arguments on Column D,F, and C are making sure it's an active robotics employee and in the proper location. That first line is trying to say (show me all the employees who didn't meet their expectation. But this result seems inconsistent. The sum of the brackets didn't equal to the total, so I did some digging. I noticed that, despite all ranges being locked. The countifs returned different results when moved to different cells. I should elaborate that the source and the formula summary were on separate tabs. But to explain what I'm noticing, here is the same formula dragged down and right a number of times. I would expect this formula to give me the same count no matter where it's placed. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
[Locked Formula Dragged Down and Right Showing Different Results Despite Same Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ0kk.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Yes, we can't really work on this if you don't provide a samole sheet, with sample data and the desired outcome you'd like.  Make sure the sharing options lets anyone edit it.

Comment: Sorry, I really cannot give access to the original but for now the problem seems to have fixed itself. Google might have been having server issues or something causing incorrect outcomes. Not too sure but if it happens again, I will try and re-create in a smaller sample sheet and share that instead.

Comment: Note that we never want access to your original sheet.  We want to have a sample sheet, with sample (non-confidential) data, and the formulae you've tried so far, and the desired outcome you'd like, typed in if necessary.  This makes it easiest for people to try to answer your question, without each person having to recreate what you are describing with your text.